# C++ Template Metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm just starting out with template metaprogramming so I'm just trying to make some basic things to begin with. I got Size and Lookup "methods" working for a BST, so I decided to try making a String class. I have this code in a cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Null;

// String
template <char C, typename S>
struct String {
  static const char chr = C;
  typedef S tail;
};

// ToString
template <typename S>
struct ToString;

template <char C, typename S>
struct ToString<String<C, S> > {
  static const string str;
};

template <char C, typename S>
const string ToString<String<C, S> >::str = C + ToString<S>::str; // (*)

template <char C>
struct ToString<String<C, Null> > {
  static const string str;
};

template <char C>
const string ToString<String<C, Null> >::str = C + ""; // to make it a string

int main() {
  typedef String<'H', String<'e', String<'l', String<'l',
             String<'o', Null> > > > > myString;
  cout << ToString<myString>::str << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This code outputs "Hell" when I run it. What am I doing wrong in the base case? It seems to have something to do with the "", because I used to have `C + ToString<S>::str` as `"" + C + ToString<S>::str` on line `(*)` and the output then was random junk.

Comment: @post that's gone: I dunno, it's just an exercise to get a feel for template metaprogramming. Let's say Concat, CharAt, ToString, and Length.

Comment: *This code outputs "Hell" when I run it.* It sounds like somebody's playing halloween pranks on you =)

Comment: can you use varadic templates?

Comment: Have you tried working with `typedef String<'o', Null> myString;` to start with and then work your way up the chain?

Comment: @Dani I was thinking about ways to use variadic templates for this one as well.  It could reduce the nesting level perhaps.

Comment: @Nick What happens if you do this `const string ToString<String<C, Null> >::str = C + '\0';`?

Comment: @MP: compiler error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"" + C + ToString<S>::str` first performs pointer addition, and only later concatenation, to do string concatenation all the way do `std::string("") + C + ToString<S>::str`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: he uses it as a static member.